# How do I increase gravity over time, or when score is updated?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have an object that falls from the top of the screen. I have it working properly but as of now, I would like for the object to start falling slower then increase to falling quicker as time progresses or as the score increases. Which ever one is easiest.

This is my code for the gravity on the object

```
private func setupPhysics() {
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -5.8)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

This is my code for the score update label.

```
private func updateScoreLabel() {
    scoreLabel.text = String(score)
```

Right now, the object is falling at -5.8 which is fine, ill probably make it a little slower to start but I would like to get it to gradually increase the rate its falling at.

Comment: You already know how to set gravity, and you already know when score is updated, you can finish answering your own question without the need of anybody here.  Apply what you know and you will do fine.

Comment: I think that is fair to say.. but if I knew how to answer my own question I wouldn't have posted here..

Comment: Of course you would,  many people are lazy and want the answer instead of figuring it out.  Like I said, you know how to set gravity, you know when score is updated.  Your question reformed is "how do I set gravity when score is updated?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property for gravity with an observer to change the world's gravity every time it changes:

```
var gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -5.8) {
                 didSet {
                         physicsWorld.gravity = gravity
                        }
                 }
var gravityScaleFactor : CGFloat = 0.9     // Gravity changes this much when score is updated
```

Change your setup to be:

```
private func setupPhysics() {
    physicsWorld.gravity = gravity
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

(You may not need to set the physicWorld's gravity here, as it might be set by the oberver for the gravity property when gravity is initialised).

Adjust gravity when you change the score:

```
private func updateScoreLabel() {
    scoreLabel.text = String(score) 
    gravity.dx *= gravityScaleFactor
```

As the gravity scale factor is a variable, you can change it based upon difficulty level, power-ups etc and as we change the world’s gravity via a property observer on the gravity property, we can change the property anywhere and know that the world's gravity will change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the code, just an update heres how i fixed the error

I changed "gravity.dx *= gravityScaleFactor" 

to be 

"gravity.dx = CGFloat(gravityScaleFactor)"

Comment: Sorry Colin - I'll edit the answer to initialise GravityScaleFactor as a  CGFloat.